# How to add a template reference on the component with Angular 2 router

Tags: angular

I've just setup the router in my application and I would like to get the reference of the component in my parent component.

Here is my router:

```
export const router: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'index', component: Component1 },
  { path: 'page2', component: Component2 },
  { path: 'page3', component: Component3 }
];
```

And inside my parent component I would like to get the reference of either `Component1`, `Component2` or `Component3` depending of which one is in the page. How am I suppose to do that?

I was trying to put a component reference (`#componentRef`) on the components in some way so I can use `@ViewChild('#componentRef')` inside my parent component, but witout success.

Can anyone tell me if that's possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Create a shared service with a `componentMounted(comp: ElementRef)` (or whatever type you'd like in your parent) function that emits the `comp`every time it's called (for example via a `Subject`). Subscribe to that in your parent and call `componentMounted` from your childrens `onInit()` maybe? Just an idea

Comment: Why do you need this reference? What are you trying to achieve? This looks like an XY question.

Answer (score 0):

inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot and use ActivatedRouteSnapshot.component reference

ref: https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot